# How do I change the amount of tests for a custom generator?

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

So I have a property `p :: Int -> Bool`. I need to test it with a custom generator `g :: Gen Int`. This works and I can run

```
quickCheckResult $ forAll g p
```

I however want to have it run more than 100 tests.
The documentation says use [`withMaxSuccess`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.14.1/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#v:withMaxSuccess). This works for

```
quickCheck (withMaxSuccess 1000 p)
```

but not for

```
quickCheckResult $ forAll g (withMaxSuccess 1000 p)
```

because it results in a:

```
<interactive>:38:23: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Int -> prop0’
                  with actual type ‘Property’
    • Possible cause: ‘withMaxSuccess’ is applied to too many arguments
      In the second argument of ‘forAll’, namely
        ‘(withMaxSuccess 10000 p)’
      In the expression:
        forAll g (withMaxSuccess 10000 p)
      In an equation for ‘it’:
          it = forAll g (withMaxSuccess 10000 p)
```

It seems that `withMaxSuccess` takes the `Int->Bool` and makes it a `Property`

How can I run `forAll` for a arbitrary amount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to compose the expressions slightly differently:

```
quickCheckResult $ withMaxSuccess 1000 $ forAll g p
```

or, if you prefer brackets:

```
quickCheckResult ((withMaxSuccess 1000) (forAll g p))
```

---

Looking at the types should explain why that works:

```
Prelude Test.QuickCheck> :t forAll g p
forAll g p :: Property

Prelude Test.QuickCheck> :t withMaxSuccess 1000
withMaxSuccess 1000 :: Testable prop => prop -> Property

Prelude Test.QuickCheck> :t (withMaxSuccess 1000) (forAll g p)
(withMaxSuccess 1000) (forAll g p) :: Property
```

Since `Property` is a `Testable` instance, the types line up.